# Conjugation map in quadratic integer rings is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, quadratic-integer-rings

Let $d$ be a square free integer such that $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and let $R$ be the ring
$$
R = \left\{a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}  \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
I am trying to show that the map
\begin{align*}
  \phi:& R \longrightarrow R\\
  a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2} &\mapsto a + b\frac{1-\sqrt{d}}{2}
\end{align*}
is an automorphism of $R$.  This would then imply that there exists an integer $c$ such that
$$
  b\frac{1-\sqrt{d}}{2} = c\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}
$$
What can $c$ be?

Comment: Why do you deduce that "This would then imply that there exists an integer $c$..."? It is not true.

Comment: @Nulhomologous because if not, then the map is not well defined.

Comment: I don't see why it is not. What happens is that $b(1-\sqrt{d})/2=b+(-b)(1+\sqrt{d})/2$.

Comment: It’s not true that there needs to be a $c$ as you claim. In order to show that map is surjective directly you need to find  $a+b\dfrac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ that get mapped to $e+f\dfrac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$, which is different from what you claim. You seem to be under the impression that you just need to compare the coefficients. Hint: try to separate the fraction!